# Number of natural solutions of exponential equation

Tags: exponential-function, diophantine-equations

To find number and nature of solutions of equation
$$ 2^p + 2^q+ 2^r= 2^s$$
where $p,q,r,s\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p\ge q\ge r\ge s$.

This is a intermediate part of question at which i m stuck.

Comment: This has no solutions as written. $2^p\ge 2^q \ge 2^r \ge 2^s > 0$, so $2^p + 2^q + 2^r > 2^s$.

Comment: how did you get last part?

Comment: Maybe should drop inequality reference to $s.$ But I don't know what the larger problem is-- cold you sketch that?

Comment: @maveric The sum of three positive numbers is strictly greater than any of them individually.

Comment: If you drop the "$\ge s$", you have $2^p + 2^{p-1} + 2^{p-1} = 2^{p+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $p,q,r,s\in\mathbb{N}$, therefore$$p\ge q\ge r\ge s\implies2^p\ge 2^q\ge 2^r\ge 2^s$$Thus, $2^p+2^q+2^r>2^s$, which clearly shows that there are no such $(p,q,r,s)$ that satisfies $$2^p+2^q+2^r=2^s$$